# CSS Mobile Optimization not working for mobile

Tags: css, mobile-website, screen-resolution

So last night I uploaded my completely new website to Heroku using React, and when I woke up this morning just to 'admire my website', I found out that it's not showing up as it should in terms of mobile optimization, even though I have specifically made it compatible with numerous devices and tablets. I don't have any code to show you, except the current '@media' code snippets that I am using to target all of the devices listed in Google Chrome developer Tools (Samsung S5, Nexus, iPhones and iPads). This is what I have so far to cover everything:

Website:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {}
```

Galaxy S:

```
@media screen and (width: 360px) {

    @media screen and (height: 640px) {

    }
}
```

Nexus 5X

```
@media screen and (width: 412px) {}
```

Nexus 6P

```
@media screen and (width: 412px) {

    @media screen and (height: 732px) {
    }
}
```

iPhone 7 & 8

```
@media screen and (width: 375px) {

    @media screen and (height: 667px) {
    }
}
```

iPhone 7 & 8 Plus

```
@media screen and (width: 414px) {

    @media screen and (height: 736px) {
    }
}
```

iPhone X

```
@media screen and (width: 375px) {

    @media screen and (height: 812px) {
    }
}
```

And the strange part is; when I was using localhost in Google Chrome (and Dev Tools, to show the screen of the particular device, it all showed up properly. However, when I go to the website still using the selected device resolution, it shows up perfect. But when I use my iPhone 7 Plus it all looks messed up. What may seem to be the problem here?

EDIT: I have done this before, and it worked perfectly. What I have done different this time, is that I am currently using create-react-app. Last time I used Sass and webpack, could this be the issue?

Comment: Can you provide the specific piece of HTML and CSS that causes the iPhone to look messed up? Also, since "messed up" is rather subjective, can you post screenshots of how it's supposed to look and how it actually looks?

Comment: Main problem here: Designing for specific _devices_ in the first place. Apart from that, just showing a few media queries does not make the problem reproducible. And even if we considered these queries “correct” for a moment - that still doesn’t tell us how you formatted any elements inside those, you could have still specified `width: 10000px` for some element inside your <320px media query ...

Comment: @CBroe I understand that perfectly. The main problem here, is that it's probably 10,15-000 lines of CSS code, because it's a huge project. But I don't really see how it somehow ends up showing incorrect on my personal device, when it shows up perfectly using Chrome Developer Tools? I have tested the website using all of the different resolutions that the tool provides without any errors.

Comment: First of all, clear the cache on the device, to exclude the possibility that you’re simply getting fooled by that. If that doesn’t fix the issue already, then I would recommend using a service like BrowserStack, or connecting the device to your computer, so that you can properly debug, use the browser dev tools, etc.

Comment: I see. When I changed my @media queries listed above with 'min-width', it seemed to display 'more properly'. However, I also noticed that fonts etc are missing. Could all of this just be a failed Heroku build?

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding so much in CSS , have you tried adding :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This should do the trick for all devices.

Comment: I have also added that. The problem is that specific components etc are supposed to display a certain way, that's why I need to go such in detail like that.